# VBA across multiple worksheets

Tags: vba, excel

I perform this code 11 times on my macro

```
Windows("LOFORM.xls").Activate
Sheets("Becke").Select
Range("A6:J25").Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("Comp Reform LO.xls").Activate
Sheets("Becke").Select
Range("A6").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
```

for all different sheets. Instead of having this entire code 11 separate time with different sheet names can I condense it?

Comment: [INTERESTING READ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select)

Answer (score 4):

This is much mroe compact, but also as it avoids all selects, activates and working with the clip board it will also be much faster.

```
Windows("Comp Reform LO.xls").Sheets("Becke").Range("A6:J25") = _
Windows("LOFORM.xls").Sheets("Becke").Range("A6:J25")
```

If you have this code 11 times through out your code you should turn it into its own sub, and simply call it as `CopyValues()` or something.

Or if the code 11 times is similar but different locations you could also pass in the Workbook and worksheet params:

```
    Sub SampleCopyValues(DestinationWorkSheet As Worksheet)
        DestinationWorkSheet.Range("A6:J25") = _
        Windows("LOFORM.xls").Sheets("Becke").Range("A6:J25")
    End Sub
```

Then you could call it as `SampleCopyValues(Windows("Comp Reform LO.xls").Sheets("Becke"))`